# X11/Xlib.h: No such file or directory Windows 10

Tags: c++, x11, fltk

I'm working on a school project using FLTK lib to build some graphs with c++:

Here is the source of the basic tuto :

https://github.com/cortical-iv/hello_fltk

when building this code with the command make, I'm getting this error :

> X11/Xlib.h: No such file or directory

I searched about this and found that generally X11 lib are used on Linux systems!

So please, any idea how can I make this work on windows !

Comment: From the website https://www.fltk.org: "FLTK is a cross-platform C++ GUI toolkit for UNIX/Linux (X11), Microsoft Windows ...". So, it should work on Windows too.

Comment: What do you use to build your Windows C++ applications? Are you building in command-line, or you use VisualStudio or similar? No matter what you use, you should read this: https://www.fltk.org/doc-1.4/intro.html#intro_windows

Comment: I succeeded running the the initial FLTK tutorial from this link : http://www.c-jump.com/bcc/common/Talk2/Cxx/FltkInstallVC/FltkInstallVC.html BUT while trying to adapt it to my case, I'm getting this error now :
Error LNK2001 unresolved external symbol "public: __thiscall Simple_window::Simple_window(struct Graph_lib::Point,int,int,class std::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> > const &)" (??0Simple_window@@QAE@UPoint@Graph_lib@@HHABV?$basic_string@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator@D@2@@std@@@Z) fltk_win32_app

Answer (score 1):

Try adding to Makefile line 2 `fltk-config --cflags`:

```
CFLAG = -std=c++14 `fltk-config --cflags`
```

You are probably compiling for 64-bit Windows. FLTK requires that WIN32 be defined even if it is compiled on 64-bit Windows. If WIN32 is not defined, then the FLTK headers will include files used on LINUX operating systems instead of Windows.

Comment: I succeeded running the the initial FLTK tutorial from this link : http://www.c-jump.com/bcc/common/Talk2/Cxx/FltkInstallVC/FltkInstallVC.html BUT while trying to adapt it to my case, I'm getting this error now :
Error LNK2001 unresolved external symbol "public: __thiscall Simple_window::Simple_window(struct Graph_lib::Point,int,int,class std::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> > const &)" (??0Simple_window@@QAE@UPoint@Graph_lib@@HHABV?$basic_string@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator@D@2@@std@@@Z) fltk_win32_app

Comment: @MohamedLamineBarghouda: That is a linker error. That means you do not have the .lib file or the Project Properties Linker settings are not set to use it. It could also be that you built the library with different settings than your project. Some of the noise you see with @ and other symbols is to encode differences between Debug/Release and Static/DLL Single/Multithreaded. Make all of those settings match up.

Answer (score 1):

FTR: it is correct that FLTK 1.3.x (and the older 1.1.x) requires the compiler macro `WIN32` to be set by the build system, i.e. the command line or in Visual Studio in the compiler setup. This is (was) a non-standard approach and has been changed in FLTK 1.4.

In FLTK 1.4 (not yet released) we use the standard `_WIN32` macro (with leading underscore) which is usually defined in all known compiler environments on Windows [1]. This is true for 32-bit as well as 64-bit compilations.

[1] except if you build using the Cygwin target with the Cygwin dll (POSIX compatibility layer). (If you don't know what that is, don't care.)